# How to enable full variable view in Zend Studio 11.0 Debug Expression details pane

Tags: zend-studio

In Zend Studio 11.0 Debug mode Expression details pane variable length is truncated to 1024

How to see whole variable in(details pane)?

Setting limit to zero(unlimited) or big number is ignored, like there is override somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Max data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd55g.jpg) It's overridden in Debugger->configure...->Max data field